# Android playing mp3 from url

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to get my android app to play an mp3 file from an url but I get this error that I simply don't understand. It says "Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side. Unable to to create media player" I know the file is there and available.

Here's my code.

---

```
package com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> urlsformp3s=new ArrayList<>();
    private MediaPlayer firstmediaplayer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        urlsformp3s.add("http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/Dvorak-Symphony9-2-from-the-New-World.mp3");
        urlsformp3s.add("http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/saint-saens-carnival-of-the-animals-the-swan.mp3");
        Log.d("we're at", "1");

        firstmediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();

        Log.d("we're at", "2");

        try {
                    Log.d("we're at", "3");
                    firstmediaplayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(urlsformp3s.get(0)));
                    Log.d("we're at", "4");
                    firstmediaplayer.prepare();
                    Log.d("we're at", "5");
                    firstmediaplayer.start();
                    Log.d("we're at", "6");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Oh no!", "error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```

---

and the log says

---

```
> 06-26 00:59:18.530 2920-2920/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
> 06-26 00:59:18.840 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm:
> VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
> (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) 06-26 00:59:18.840
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from
> method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
> 06-26 00:59:18.840 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm:
> VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15144:
> Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested
> (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z 06-26 00:59:18.840
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 06-26 00:59:18.840
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
> 06-26 00:59:18.840 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm:
> VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15148:
> Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode
> (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode; 06-26
> 00:59:18.840 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm: VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 06-26 00:59:18.910
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged
> 06-26 00:59:18.910 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm:
> VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15047:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged (I)V 06-26
> 00:59:18.910 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm: VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008 06-26 00:59:18.980
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from
> method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged 06-26
> 00:59:18.980 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm: VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 15043:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V 06-26
> 00:59:18.980 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm: VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007 06-26 00:59:18.990
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
> 06-26 00:59:18.990 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm:
> VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 06-26
> 00:59:18.990 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm: VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 06-26 00:59:18.990
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
> android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 06-26 00:59:18.990
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
> resolve virtual method 446: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType
> (I)I 06-26 00:59:18.990 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3
> D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 06-26 00:59:19.020
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from
> method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable 06-26
> 00:59:19.020 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm: VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 387:
> Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable
> (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
> 06-26 00:59:19.020 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm:
> VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 06-26 00:59:19.020
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 I/dalvikvm: Could not find
> method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced
> from method
> android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity 06-26
> 00:59:19.020 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/dalvikvm: VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 389:
> Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity
> (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
> 06-26 00:59:19.020 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm:
> VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 06-26 00:59:19.030
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/we're at: 1 06-26 00:59:19.040
> 2920-2923/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed
> 233K, 5% free 6837K/7175K, paused 2ms+2ms 06-26 00:59:19.060
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/we're at: 2 06-26 00:59:19.060
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/we're at: 3 06-26 00:59:19.060
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open
> file on client side, trying server side 06-26 00:59:19.060
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 E/MediaPlayer: Unable to to
> create media player 06-26 00:59:19.060
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/Oh no!: error 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:844) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:806) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:761) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at
> com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
> 06-26 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1092)
> 06-26 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
> 06-26 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
> 06-26 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
> 06-26 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
> 06-26 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-26 00:59:19.060
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4447) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-26 00:59:19.060
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
> 06-26 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 06-26
> 00:59:19.060 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 W/System.err:    
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-26 00:59:19.110
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/libEGL: loaded
> /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so 06-26 00:59:19.160
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/libEGL: loaded
> /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so 06-26 00:59:19.180
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/libEGL: loaded
> /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so 06-26 00:59:19.200
> 2920-2920/com.tenn.klaszetterlund.mp3 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug
> mode 0
```

please help!

Answer (score 1):

I am being a dumbkopf. The problem was that the internet permissions were not added to the AndroidManifest.xml
Just add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```